# JavaScript Date() Constructor returning date with different timezone based on string input structure?

Tags: javascript, date

I'm seeing some odd behaviour when leveraging the Date constructor for JS. My understanding is that if you use the the "YYYY-MM-DD" string format as a parameter to the constructor, the resulting Date object will be in UTC.

For example:

`new Date("2022-11-01")`  gives "2022-11-01T00:00:00.000Z" which I would expect as it's in UTC

BUT the below return it using my client local time:

`new Date("2022-11-1")` and `new Date("11-1-2022")` return "2022-11-01T04:00:00.000Z"

Can someone please explain what's going on here? I'm unable to find much documentation about supported date string inputs and their expected outputs

Comment: _“Note: Parsing of date strings with the `Date` constructor (and `Date.parse`, which works the same way) is **strongly discouraged** due to browser differences and inconsistencies.”_ — From the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#parameters).

Comment: The parser resolves timestamps to identify an instant in time represented by a time value, an offset in milliseconds from  1 Jan 1970 UTC (the ECMAScript epoch). That is the sole data value of *Date* instances, they do not have location or timezone information. The time value can be presented as a date and time in any timezone or calendar supported by ECMA-262 (Gregorian) and ECMA-402 (Gregorian, Buddhist, Chinese, Islamic and 14 others). The default for the various *toString* methods is Gregorian, the *toLocaleString* method can be used for other calendars and timezones.